# issue when real time updating a-sky src

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I have simple python based websocket server which passes video frames as base64 string to client.

My client code

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5678/")
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log("Event received: ", event.data.length)
  let data = event.data.slice(0, -1);
  document.getElementById('sky').setAttribute('src', "data:image/jpg;base64," + data);
};
```

When I use

```
//html
<img id="sky" src="" >
```

as image container, a "video" is produced.

But when I swtich to

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <img id="sky" src="sky.png">
  </a-assets>
  <a-sky src="#sky"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

the image container get stuck at first frame, and although the src attribute of img element is updated, the image on web page doesn't change.

I've looked documentation and weren't able to find anything. What should I give attention?

Comment: are you using  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
   in the html>?

Comment: try in client.py file , AFRAME.getElement.....

Comment: yes, I am using exactly that version. AFRAME is defined and returns and object. getElement is not defined for that object.

Comment: are you running aframe from a cdn or ur server. bcoz if its cdn xss is not possible

Comment: it is from cdn. but i don't think this is xss issue. the first picture is rendered without problem.

Comment: https://github.com/supereggbert/aframe-htmlembed-component in this it is written clearly that , "All styles and images must be in the same origin or allow access via CORS; this allows the component to embed all of the assets required to render the html properly to the canvas via the foreignObject element."

Comment: Maybe the material, or texture object needs setting the `needsUpdate` flag to `true`. You could try doing this upon each websocket update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access the `<a-sky>`'s material and texture and set the `needsUpdate` flag.
For example in a custom component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  init: function() {
    // wait until the object is loaded
    this.el.addEventListener("loaded", e => {
       // grab the mesh
       var mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh")
       // expose the material
       this.material = mesh.material
    })
  },
  tick: function() {
    // when the material is exposed - set the update flag on each tick
    if (!this.material) return;
    this.material.map.needsUpdate = true
  }
}
```

Canvas texture example [here](https://glitch.com/%7Egftruj-aframe-ctxtex).

---

Or you can do this with a more direct approach, by accessing the material component:

```
// Providing the a-sky entity is loaded and ready
a_sky.components.material.material.map.needsUpdate = true

// Untangling it from the left to right:
// entity -> component list -> material component ->
// THREE.js Material object -> texture -> needsUpdate flag
```

Comment: after your comment, i've started to look up a-frame/three source code again, and i came up with the solution `a_sky.components.material.material.map.needsUpdate = true`. this one is a lot better and clean. thanks.

Comment: @marmeladze was hoping an excessive answer would be clearer :) 
I've added your solution with a word of comment what is going on there.